# What is the best way of showing conditional statements in html using php?

Tags: php, html

What is the best way of showing conditional statements in html using php, for some time I've been using the following:

```
<body>

    <?php if ($showDiv): ?>
    <div class='row'>
        <input type='text' name='input' />
    </div>  
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($showDiv): ?>
    <div class='row'>
        <input type='text' name='input2' />
    </div>  
    <?php endif ?>

</body>
```

Comment: that is the way i do it, should be fine!

Comment: If it is a small amount of text, like what you have, I would just `echo` the content. It saves from closing and opening the PHP tags

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that Samuel. It saves closing opening tags, but it has several disadvantages. Less readable, dificult to indent, problems with escaping quotes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing. However, you could combine your output since the test you perform is the same (and assuming that nothing else appears between these two blocks):

```
<body>

    <?php if ($showDiv): ?>
    <div class='row'>
        <input type='text' name='input' />
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <input type='text' name='input2' />
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
```

Don't forget the semi-colon after the `endif` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it:

```
<body>

<?php if (isset($showDiv)){ ?>
<div class='row'>
    <input type='text' name='input' />
</div>  
<?php } ?>

<?php if (isset($showDiv)){ 

if ($showDiv == "show"){ ?>
<div class='row'>
    <input type='text' name='input2' />
</div>  
<?php } } ?>

</body>
```

You should check is your value is not empty too ;)

Saludos.

Comment: Robert Rozas, the way the OP described it is correct syntax and common practice for conditional statements in view scripts. $showDiv would be a boolean I wouldn't do any string comparences

Comment: May be i missunderstood the question.....anyway, if you do not check that showDiv is defined, then you should have a lot of warnings in that kind of script